# Modular Equivalence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove that if a and b are integers such that a|b and b > 0, then
(x mod b) mod a = x mod a for any x.

Solution: As a|b, we have b = pa for some integer p. Let x mod b = r, then we
have x = bq + r = apq + r for some integer q. Hence, we have
x mod a = r mod a = (x mod b) mod a

I don't see how the author of this proof went from x = bq + r = apq + r to x mod a = r mod a. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $x=apq+r$, and $r$ is the class of $x$ modulo $b$.

So, looking at this equality modulo $a$, we have $x \equiv r\; (\textrm{mod}\; a)$ since $apq \equiv 0\; (\textrm{mod}\; a)$. This proves the result, since $x \equiv r\; (\textrm{mod}\; b)$.

Comment: Same question as above, where does apq≡0(mod a) come from?

Comment: $a \mid apq$, so the remainder upon dividing $apq$ by $a$ is zero. Thus, $apq \equiv 0\; (\textrm{mod}\; a)$. Remember how equivalence modulo an integer $m$ is defined: $\alpha \equiv \beta \; (\textrm{mod} \; n)$ iff $n\mid \alpha - \beta$.

Answer (score 1):

$\overbrace{(x\ {\rm mod}\ b)}^{\large r}\ {\rm mod}\ a\, =\, \overbrace{(x\!-\!bq)}^{\large r}\ {\rm mod}\ a\, =\, (x\!-\!apq)\ {\rm mod}\ a\, =\, x\ {\rm mod}\ a$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally $\ x \equiv y\pmod{ap}\,\Rightarrow\,x\equiv y\pmod a\ $ by $\ a\mid ap\mid x-y$

Yours is the special case $\, y = (x\ {\rm mod}\ ap),\,$  using $\ x\equiv y\pmod a\,\Rightarrow\, (x\ {\rm mod}\ a) = (y\ {\rm mod}\ a).$

Generally, as here, it is much easer to work first with *congruences* then, if need be, reduce to remainders (= least reps $\ge 0)\,$ only at the end.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the step you asked about, we have that $x = apq + r$. When we work modulo $a$, $a=0$, so $$\begin{align} x \pmod{a} &= \\ apq + r \pmod{a} &= \\apq\pmod{a} + r\pmod{a} &= \\0 + r \pmod{a} &= \\r\pmod{a}.\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't understand. Why is a = 0?